# My wireless card suddenly stops working

Tags: 16.04, wireless, atheros

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 and my wireless card sometimes suddenly stops working after some use. When I restart the machine, goes back online.

In the network manager menu, it says 'disconnected' and below wifi-networks says: device not ready.

I can't make it back online, unless I restart.

My wireless device is Qualcomm Atheros QCA8171.

[EDIT]
[wireless-info.txt](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/TzFPQm2nWR/)

Comment: You can get more information with `journalctl /usr/sbin/NetworkManager`

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Please review [this q&a](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos) and then return here to [edit] necessary information into your question. Thank you for helping us help you!